# Replace line range, defined by variable, with a string

Tags: sed

I would like to replace a specific line range with Nan values. My line range is defined by variables for the first and last line I would like to replace, so for example:

```
startrow=3
endrow=6
```

Input file:

```
1
4
3
2
6
1
3
4
```

Desired output file:

```
1
4
Nan
Nan
Nan
Nan
3
4
```

I think this should be possible using sed. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *startline,endlineCOMMAND* syntax with sed. For example:

```
$ sed "${startrow},${endrow}s/.*/Nan/" file.txt
```